# How to append texts/html to the current created draft in Gmail Addons in the real time

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I have this scenario once the user clicks on the LINK text button:

1. If the draft box is not opened, create a new draft reply and append the link.
2. If the draft box is opened, just append the needed text to the written texts by the user.

I could be able to create a new draft with the needed text, but I've some of difficulties to figure out the second scenario! I could be able to update the created draft, but in the background and the user can't see those changes until he goes to the draft folder and opens the draft message!

```
//Build the link text button
var appendLink = CardService.newTextButton().setText("Link").setComposeAction(CardService.newAction().setFunctionName("appendTemplateLinkBtnAction").setParameters({templateLink:theCustomizedTemplateLinkText}), CardService.ComposedEmailType.REPLY_AS_DRAFT);

//-----------------------------------------------------------------//
//Append the customized template link button action 
function appendTemplateLinkBtnAction(e){  
  //Get the access token
  var theAccessToken = e.messageMetadata.accessToken;
  GmailApp.setCurrentMessageAccessToken(theAccessToken);

  var theTemplateLink = e.parameters.templateLink;
  var theMessageId = e.messageMetadata.messageId;
  var theMessage = GmailApp.getMessageById(theMessageId);
  var theDraft = theMessage.createDraftReply(theTemplateLink);

  //Build the draft
  return CardService.newComposeActionResponseBuilder().setGmailDraft(theDraft).build();
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, for the second scenario? That code looks like it is only for the first scenario

Comment: @tehhowch I've tried to use `update` function, but it doesn't change the texts in the real time in front of the user. [Update doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-draft#update(String,String,String)).

Answer (score 0):

For the 1st part, you can provide options to your draft.

```
  var draft = GmailApp.createDraft(
    email,
    subject,
    '',
    {
      htmlBody: errorText + body,
      attachments: []
    }
  )
  return CardService.newComposeActionResponseBuilder()
    .setGmailDraft(draft).build();
```

Comment: Thanks! But I've figured out the first situation and works fine. Not sure how to fix the second scenario. If the user opened the box before, I can't create the draft box again or append any texts.